# Enum.ToString("g") in objective-c

Tags: c#, objective-c, enums

In c#, you declare an enum and can print it's literal by using the `enumVariable.ToString("g")`
what is the command in objective-c to do this

for example in c# i can write the following:

```
class Sample 
{
    enum Colors {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow = 12};

    public static void Main() 
    {
       Colors myColor = Colors.Yellow;
       Console.WriteLine("myColor.ToString(\"d\") = {0}", myColor.ToString("d"));         
       Console.WriteLine("myColor.ToString(\"g\") = {0}", myColor.ToString("g"));
   }
}

// This example produces the following results:
// myColor.ToString("d") = 12
// myColor.ToString("g") = Yellow
```

I know I can create an array of strings to hold the values or write a function with switch case but that seems a solution appropriate to a c language written in 1970 :)

If you know of an elegant solution please let me know.

Comment: You just need to print it in console?

Comment: C# is a script language, so it can do a lot of "magic" beyond the scene. In obj-c, since it's a strict superset of c, you have to deal with the old c enumerator. I'm afraid you need to use an array of string or switch case, since in obj-c / c enum are just value big enough to hold at least int value.

Comment: Not at all. enum is an int or uint but NSString is an object with class factory methods.

Answer (score 2):

The most common case when developer wants receive a string from enum value is to use it (string) as a value/key for complex object (XML, JSON, URL, etc.).

Not always you want exactly the same string from enum value. In Objective-C you should use mapping. Create NSDictionary with keys from enum (wrapped in NSNumber) and values of NSString type.

```
// your enum
enum
{
    kAPXStateOpened,
    kAPXStateClosed,
    kAPXStateUnknown
};
...

// static map
static NSDictionary *theStateMap = nil;
static dispatch_once_t theStateMapDispatch = 0;
dispatch_once(&theStateMapDispatch,
^{
    theStateMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @"opened", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:kAPXStateOpened],
                @"closed", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:kAPXStateClosed],
                @"broken", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:kAPXStateUnknown],
                nil];
});

self.currentState = kAPXStateOpened;
NSString *theStringValueFromState = [theStateMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.currentState]];
NSLog(theStringValueFromState); // "opened"
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums in ObjC are integers with a defined set of values rather than objects. Hence there are methods on them. There may be some C functions which do stuff with enums, but I'm not familiar with them. (Would be interested if anyone else knows them).

Because enums are integers it's also possible to put undefined values into variables which use the enum type.

Here's an example:

```
typedef enum {
    enumValueA,
    enumValueB
} EnumName;

// Useful when you want to define specific values.
typedef enum {
    enumX = 1, 
    enumY = 100
} AnotherEnum;
```

and in the code:

```
EnumName x = enumValueA;
```

However these are also valid:

```
EnumName x = 0; // = enumValueA
EnumName x = 3; // Not defined in the enum.
```

So enums are basically a way to use English like names for a specific set of integer values.

To get strings from them for inclusion in UIs and logging, you will need to manually map the enum values to strings. A string array where the enum values provide the index is relatively simple to put in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
int someInt = [NString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yourEnumVariable];
```